# Automatically filled input not read in Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, authentication, shiny

I am coding a login form for an R application. Everything is fine except for 1 thing: I encrypt passwords with MD5 everytime a keyup event is triggered. Until now, the result is correct. The issue rises when I click the submit button. I try to read the text from this encrypted input in R but Shiny reads **""**, that is to say, the empty string. I've checked it and certainly it's not empty. The only way does Shiny read anything out of this encrypted input, is that I manually type something.

How can I read this password in the backend? Below my Html, JS and R code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user"> User (test) </label>
            <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" id="user" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password"> Password (test) </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" 
                     id="password"/>
            <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control shiny-bound-input" 
                     id="pass" style="display:none;"/>
        </div>
        <button id="loginButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default action-button shiny-bound-input">Login</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("#password").keyup(function(){
      $("#pass").val(md5($("#password").val()));
    });
});
```

---

```
if (input$loginButton > 0) {
    Username <- isolate(input$user)
    Password <- isolate(input$password)
    print(Password)
}
```

Comment: You can probably use `Shiny.onInputChange` javascript to send the password to the backend. Add `Shiny.onInputChange("encrypted_pass", md5(...));` somewhere in your js code, and access by `input$encrypted_pass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @warmoverflow I could make it work as intended.

The keyup event ended like this

```
$("#password").keyup(function(){
          Shiny.onInputChange("pass", md5($("#password").val()));
        });
```

and when the button is clicked, pass is already encrypted and ready to be read.